# How to properly get onedrive access token via php and curl

Tags: php, curl, onedrive

Am trying to get onedrive access token.
**Here is the Request:**

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client_id}&scope={scope}
    &response_type=token&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}
```

**Here is Response:**

```
https://myapp.com/auth-redirect#access_token=EwC...EB
  &authentication_token=eyJ...3EM&token_type=bearer&expires_in=3600
  &scope=onedrive.readwrite&user_id=3626...1d
```

I have implemented the two code below in other to get the access token but am having error below when page is being redirected for login.

**AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_id'.**

**Scope** property is space seperated hence see onedrive documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/graph-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online)

**code 1**

```
$data_string = array(
"client_id" => "myclient id",
"response_type" => "token",
"redirect_uri" => "http://localhost/test/callback.php"
"scope" => ['files.readwrite', 'offline_access'],
); 
$data = json_encode($data_string); 
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array( 
CURLOPT_URL => "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?", 
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", 
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, 
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30, 
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1, 
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET", 
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "$data", 
));

$result = curl_exec($curl); 
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

**code 2**

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array( 
CURLOPT_URL => "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=myclientid-goes-here&scope=files.readwrite.all offline_access
    &response_type=token&redirect_uri=http://localhost/test/callback.php", 
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", 
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, 
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30, 
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1, 
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET", 
//CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "$data", 
));

$result = curl_exec($curl); 
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved using **http_build_query()** function
hence

```
$data = http_build_query($data_string, '', '&');
```